# Update a row in one table with data grouped from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I have 2 tables:

- `Table1`: Id   CommonId   Table2Id   Col1   Col2
- `Table2`: Id   CommonId   Col1   Col2

Initially `Table2Id` is `null`. There can be multiple rows in `Table2` where `CommonId` is the same.

How can I set `Table2Id` to the value of `Table2.Id` matching both `CommonId` but only where the rows grouped by `Table2.CommonId` is 1?

I tried the following:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Table2Id = t2.Id
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id, CommonId, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM @Table2
    GROUP BY CommonId
) AS t2
    ON t1.CommonId = t2.CommonId;
```

How can I add the condition where `Cnt` is only 1?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also for better answers please see this on how to post good question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you just need to add `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` to your inner query or `WHERE t2. nt = 1` to the outer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [T N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n) for the tip. `HAVING` does the trick:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Table2Id = t2.Id
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id, CommonId
    FROM @Table2
    GROUP BY CommonId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS t2
ON t1.CommonId = t2.CommonId;
```